# Error during searching for estimators with R

Tags: r, math, statistics, dataset, runtime-error

My code:

```
#Task 1.4 Find the ML estimators of nu and eta from the grouped data.

library("xlsx")
duom1<-dataset1
duom1
k=11
library(maxLik)
ln_l3 <- function(par) {
  eta <- par[1]
  nu <- par[2]
  reziai=k-1
  f=duom1$U_i[1]*log(pweibull(duom1$Int_pab[1], shape=par[2],
                              scale = par[1], lower.tail = TRUE))+
    duom1$U_i[k]*log(1-pweibull(duom1$Int_pr[k], shape=par[2],
                                scale = par[1], lower.tail = TRUE))+
    sum(duom1$U_i[2:reziai]*log(
      pweibull(duom1$Int_pab[2:reziai], shape=par[2], scale = par[1], lower.tail = TRUE)-
        pweibull(duom1$Int_pr[2:reziai], shape=par[2], scale = par[1], lower.tail = TRUE)) )
  return(f)
}
mle <- maxLik(logLik = ln_l3, start = c(650,2))
coef(mle)
```

By executing this in R I got such error:

 Error in pweibull(duom1$Int_pab[1], shape = par[2], scale = par[1], lower.tail = TRUE) :
Non-numeric argument to mathematical function. 
 Could somebody let me know what is wrong? Also, here is a dataset used in this task:
[image]

And the output of dput(duom1):

```
structure(list(Left = c(0L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 
700L, 800L, 900L, 1000L), Right = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 
600L, 700L, 800L, 900L, 1000L, 100000L), U = c(8L, 12L, 19L, 
23L, 29L, 30L, 25L, 18L, 15L, 14L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: Please provide the dataset by pasting the output of `dput`

Comment: @starja The output of dput: function (x, file = "", control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger", 
    "niceNames", "showAttributes")) 
{
    if (is.character(file)) 
        if (nzchar(file)) {
            file <- file(file, "wt")
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
        else file <- stdout()
    .Internal(dput(x, file, .deparseOpts(control)))
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000afabe38>
<environment: namespace:base>

Comment: I mean `dput(duom1)` so of your dataset, sorry if that was not clear. You can then directly edit it into your question

Comment: @starja ok, thanks, it's done and added into question. Sorry, I'm quite new in R, hadn't used this function earlier. :)

Comment: in the function `ln_l3` you use `duom1$U_i`, `duom1$Int_pab` and `duom1$Int_pr`, but the colnames of your dataset are `Left`, `Right` and `U`, so `duom1$Int_pab` etc. returns `NULL`. Maybe you just have to change the colnames in your function?